# javascript regex exception in date format

Tags: javascript, html

Exception occurs while loading page which ahs thi regex.Please help me find what went wrong.
If I remove regex then it works .

```
 function show()
  {
    vat patt =/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$/;
    var temp="08/02/1988";
    if(isNaN(temp.match(patt)))
       alert("success");
    else
       alert("not success");

  }
```

**Exception :**
Error: missing ; before statement
Source File:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RegEx should be

```
var patt =/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d$/;
```

Issues:
1. Spelling mistake in `vat` - should be `var`
2. All `/` within the expression should be escaped with `\/`